# Removing Annoying double quotes from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I am getting annoying double quotes from `json` as I convert `html` to `json` friendly.

It can be seen in below code at the start of `<p>"` & end of `"<\p>`. How can I remove them. Tried following doesn't work.

```
$("p").html().replace(/['"]+/g, '')
```

This is dynamic html inside js variable.

```
<p>"<!--HTML icon appears here--><a href="https://www.example.com/viewer/event.jsp?ei=1434586&amp;tp_key=e8ced8705c" target="_blank">Click here for web</a><br>
<!--PDF icon appears here--><a href="../file/408427349/Index?KeyFile=1500113055" target="_blank">Press Release</a><br>
<!--PDF icon appears here--><a href="../file/4234/Index?KeyFile=234324" target="_blank">somelink</a><br>"</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to set the html once you got the text sanitized?

This should do it:

```js
var text = $('p').html().replace(/['"]+/g, '')
$('p').html(text)

// or you can just:
// $('p').html($('p').html().replace(/['"]+/g, ''))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>"<!--HTML icon appears here--><a href="https://event.web.com/viewer/event.jsp?ei=1434586&amp;tp_key=e8ced8705c" target="_blank">Click here for web</a><br>
<!--PDF icon appears here--><a href="../file/408427349/Index?KeyFile=1500113055" target="_blank">Press Release</a><br>
<!--PDF icon appears here--><a href="../file/4234/Index?KeyFile=234324" target="_blank">somelink</a><br>"</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property to remove any `'` or `"` quotes.

`/[><]['"]+[><]/g` will remove extra quotes present between opening and closing tags. It will not remove the quotes from `attribute = value` pairs.

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');

p.outerHTML = p.outerHTML.replace(/[><]['"]+[><]/g, '');
```

```html
<p>"<!--HTML icon appears here--><a href="https://event.web.com/viewer/event.jsp?ei=1434586&amp;tp_key=e8ced8705c" target="_blank">Click here for web</a><br>
<!--PDF icon appears here--><a href="../file/408427349/Index?KeyFile=1500113055" target="_blank">Press Release</a><br>
<!--PDF icon appears here--><a href="../file/4234/Index?KeyFile=234324" target="_blank">somelink</a><br>"</p>
```